# Can I select multiple div tags using getElementByTagId?

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide, getelementbyid

I am trying to show div display:none with document.getElementById to multiple div but only get it to work with one div id

```
<div id="spill" name="audit" class="audit" style="display:none;">Quantity:-
<select name='qtyspill' > 
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    }
?> 
</select>
</div>

<div id="pbox" name="audit100" class="audit" style="display:none;">Quantity:-
<select name='qtypbox' > 
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    }
?> 
</select>
</div>
```

My js

```
function getValue(x) {
  if(x.value == '0'){   
    document.getElementById('spill').style.display = 'none'; // you need a identifier for changes
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('spill').style.display = 'block';  // you need a identifier for changes
  }
}
```

How can I go about it to let it work I don't want to write multiple js as some of my audit selection can be more than 20

I have tried using Lelio suggestions as follow not sure I understand correctly but it is not showing the diff when i click on input radio button

```
<div class="rating">
       <label for="happy">1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="happy" id="r1" value="0" onChange="getValue(this)" checked />

<label for="neutral">2</label>
<input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="neutral" id="r2" value="1" onChange="getValue(this)" />

<label for="sad">3</label> 
      <input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="sad" id="r3" value="2" onChange="getValue(this)" />
</div>
```

Then my show hide div

```
<div id="audit1" name="audit1" class="audit" style="display:none;">Quantity:-
<select name='qtyspill' > 
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    }
?> 
</select>
</div>

<div id="audit2" name="audit2" class="audit" style="display:none;">Quantity:-
<select name='qtypbox' > 
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    }
?> 
</select>
```

And then suggested js code

```
function getValue(x,idName) {
  if(x.value == '0'){   
    document.getElementById(idName).style.display = 'none'; // you need a identifier for changes
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById(idName).style.display = 'block';  // you need a identifier for changes
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you prefer to use jQuery or no jQuery?

Comment: id must be unique in the dom. That's why getElementById will always return a single element. If you select by class name then you will get a collection. If you have more than one element with the same id only the first will be usable

Comment: Can you add an example of how you use `getValue`? What is x? And why is it named "getValue" when all you do is hiding or showing `div#spill`?

Comment: If there is an alternate way any suggestion?

How can I use with class name I have tried but it is not working

document.getElementsByClassName("audit ")

Comment: It was a piece of code snippet I used to show and hide one div which I tried to change to  do it on multiple div I am open on any ideas achieving this

Comment: This is my form input -snippet 
`<input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="happy" id="r1" value="0" onChange="getValue(this)" checked />`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the same function over different ids, put the id as a parameter for the function. So when you invoke it you will pass x and the id

```
function getValue(x,idName) {
  if(x.value == '0'){   
    document.getElementById(idName).style.display = 'none'; // you need a identifier for changes
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById(idName).style.display = 'block';  // you need a identifier for changes
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to select multiple items that share the same id, that is an invalid html and your js will target only the first element with that id skipping the others

Comment: I have tried your code maybe I am missing something because it is not working

Comment: you should show when and how you are invoking this function and explain what does it mean _it is not working_

Comment: First time I quote tags in comment not getting it right with ` `

Comment: This is my form input -snippet
`<input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="happy" id="r1" value="0" onChange="getValue(this)" checked />`

Comment: edito your question with the code, do not post it as comments here please. It is completely unclear. Use the <> button to create a snippet that replicates the issue